# Record new animation in Motion Builder

Tags: 3d, skeletal-animation

I was rigged a 3d character model using MotionBuilder software. now i want to record my own animation for this 3d model. im new for the motion builder and i was unable to find a good reference for learn about recording animation in motion builder.(i press the record button in time line but it says nothing to record). please help me and give me a brief introduction or reference that i can learn about creating new animation on rigged character in Autodesk MotionBuilder. thanks.... :)

Comment: "Solved myself" is a horrible answer for anyone looking for this information in the future. Please create a full answer on what you did to solve the problem or remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch 3dbuzz tutorials first. MoBu is not complicated but you need to learn it. the record button records the existing animation, so if you don't have one... you can find online mocap data
Good luck

Comment: Suggesting someone learn the tool they're using is not an answer to how to use the tool in a specific way. This doesn't address the question asked.